# Filter calendar based on today's date in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a dim_calendar as below and I would like to create a measure to show the current month and Fiscal year on a powerbi `Card`. Many thanks in advance.

```
Date          FY     Month  Year
11/19/2023   FY24     Nov   2023 
11/20/2023   FY24     Nov   2023 
11/21/2023   FY24     Nov   2023
```

if `today = 11/19/2023`  Expected Answer is  `Nov-FY24`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Measure = 
VAR x = LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[FY], 'Table'[Date], TODAY())
RETURN 
FORMAT(TODAY(), "MMM") & "-" & x
```

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot.